# Dynamic List View from database in android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-layout, android-emulator

I am developing an android app in which I have to present the user List views which changes dynamically as follows

1. When user opens for the first time it has to show "Create New" clicking on which it leads to a new form. Upon creation this is saved in a SQLite DB(stationary 1) for example.

2.When user creates and again opens app it has to show
  1.Stationary 1 Reorder
  2.Create new

Please give your valuable advice

Regards
ChinniKrishna Kothapalli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all see how to generate a list view.Then you can see how to working with SQLite database so that you can insert and retrieve from the database.Once you are able to do these now you can go for your task.The step is

```
Retrieve value from the databse

Populate the UI which has a list populated from the retrieval values and a button with text
  create and an EditText.

In onClick method of button retrieve the text from EditText and save it to the Database and
  refresh the list(adding the newly created one to the list).
```